# How to change cells with white fill to no fill?

Tags: excel, vba

I received a massive 40MB sheet from a colleague and he has no clue about formatting. Instead of hiding gridlines, he filled them with a white background. I want to find all cells with white background and change them to no fill while keeping other formats such as currency and numbers.

```
Sub White_to_no_fill_wb()

Dim ws As Worksheet


For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
        ws.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

This doesn't give me any errors but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: At the risk of asking a dumb question... are there cells with other background colors, e.g. yellow, blue, black, whatever?

Answer (score 0):

Looping through worksheets, then through the cells in the used range works:

```
Sub RemoveWhiteFilling()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myUsedRange As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set myUsedRange = ws.UsedRange
        For Each myCell In myUsedRange
            If myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
                myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            End If
        Next myCell
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, we need to set the pattern of the `Range.Interior`

```vb
Sub SetOK()
    Dim iCnt As Integer, i As Integer, aCell As Range
    iCnt = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For i = 1 To iCnt
        Worksheets(i).Activate
            
        For Each aCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            If aCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
                With aCell.Interior
                    .Pattern = xlNone
                End With
            End If
        Next aCell
   Next i  
End Sub
```

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).